# Custom collections - check if Facebook user has added it

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We just got our custom collections approved by Facebook and now want to add a button to ask user to add to their profile in our app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/

Is there a call to detect if the user has already added our custom collection to their profile page?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but that URL is broken and there is practically no documentation at all about Open Graph collections in their documentation. Are you aware of any changes they are making to this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook Collections are not supported anymore.**

See this [link](http://allfacebook.com/phasing-out-app-collections_b128973):

> We designed collections to help people express what’s important to
>   them on Timeline. However, after testing with users, we’ve found that
>   few wanted to add custom app collections to their Timelines.
>   Similarly, the traffic to apps that have incorporated custom
>   collections has been limited. As a result, we are no longer accepting
>   new collection submissions, although existing custom collections will
>   continue to function.